# Wordpress plugin development. Issue with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, where-clause

I m trying to develop a wordpress plugin that creates a table and allows the admin to add entries to the table from the backend. 
I also want the plugin to show only the entry that the admin made just then, so I am using the where clause for that, however it seems that the where clause isnt working correctly. I m able to create the table and form where admin will submit the entries.
This is the code I wrote for that:

```
$time=current_time( 'mysql' );
$r = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE time = $time ");
echo $r->time;
```

I have successfully created the column by name 'time' and have inserted the $time variable in it. But it just won't display no matter what I do. 
I hope someone will be able to notice what I missed. Please help. Thanks in advance.
***I was just missing the single quotes around the $time variable inside the sql query. Adding those quotes really solved the problem!!!!***

Comment: Surround the `$time` value with single quote

Comment: just replace your code with this  
$r = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE time = '$time' ");

Comment: Thanks a lot! raptor and ManojSharma, it really worked!!!!!! Once again Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not get why would you like to show rows created in the current second,  but if you really want to do that, use:

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE time = NOW()
```

But! It is very likely that this query will return empty as the creation time will not be exactly that second. 
Maybe you want to get all rows created today?

```
SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE DATE(time) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sir, I was just missing the single quotes around the $time variable inside the query, adding them solved the problem!

Comment: @TomaszSwider This answer is better one instead of variable use aggregate function.

Comment: @TomaszSwider  I didn't knew about the usage of DATE(time), I used it now in my project to filter history and it's working great. Thanks a lot. This website is great. You never know what new things are waiting for you.